# Not managed to get value for unchecked checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

First, don't treat this as duplicate since I do a few try & error, as well research before asking. I intended to post value from jquery including unchecked checkbox. I've tried many ways but still didn't manage to get it works, either due to structure of my code or else. Here is one of the attempt I try currently:

```js
function toggle_tip() {}
$('#l_sync_ul').click(function() {
  if ($('#l_sync_ul').prop("checked") == undefined) {
    $('#l_sync_ul').after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $('#l_sync_ul').attr("l_sync_ul") + '" value=off>')
  } else {
    $('#l_sync_ul').next().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="l_sync_ul" id="l_sync_ul" onclick="toggle_tip('ul_dept')" type="checkbox">
```

*Just ignore the 'onclicks' attribute since I'm using it for toggle the table.*

Comment: didn't get what you want. Please explain it little more

Comment: excuse me @mplungjan, is it necessary to amend 'onclicks' since I'm using for another purposes; toggle table display?

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman this question intend to get checkbox value posted on uncheck. if checked will posted 'on', then I expecting 'off' for uncheck. but the things just don't send.

Comment: If it is not checked it will not send. Deal with that on the server or in the Ajax if you are using ajax

Comment: @mplungjan I have try a few ways but it won't worked. I'm not sure if necessary to do this within ajax success function or declare another function & declare it into ajax success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want, but this will work better

```js
$('#l_sync_ul').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '" value=off>')
  } else {
    $(this).next().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="l_sync_ul" id="l_sync_ul" type="checkbox">
```

but why not have the hidden field and disable/enable it on click? Or better: If it is not checked it will not send. Deal with that on the server or in the Ajax if you are using Ajax –

Answer (score 1):

You just `.prop("checked")` will return `true` or `false`. And as you are using jQuery I would recommend you to directly bind the `change` event handler using it.

```js
$('#l_sync_ul').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $(this).after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '" value=off>')
  } else {
    $(this).next().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="l_sync_ul" id="l_sync_ul" type="checkbox">*Just ignore the 'onclicks' attribute since I'm using it for toggle the table.*
```

Comment: it just worked if the checkbox previously checked. but if previously unchecked, it won't work. I have notice this.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#l_sync_ul').prop("checked")` itself a boolean, no need to check for `undefined`.

And you can track `checkbox` with `.change` event listener.

```js
function toggle_tip() {}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#l_sync_ul').click(function() {
    if ($('#l_sync_ul').prop("checked")) {
      console.log("Checked");
      $('#l_sync_ul').after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $('#l_sync_ul').attr("l_sync_ul") + '" value=off>')
    } else {
      console.log("Un Checked");
      $('#l_sync_ul').next().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="l_sync_ul" id="l_sync_ul" onclick="toggle_tip('ul_dept')" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on latest edit, I replace `$(this).next().remove(); with $('input[value=off]').remove();`, so it will remove any element with `value=off`. It may works on certain circumstances and vice versa. See here:

*Script*

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  if (!this.checked) {
    $(this).after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '" value=off>')
  } else {
    $('input[value=off]').remove();
  }
});
```

*HTML*

```
<input type="hidden" name="l_sync_ul" value=off>
<input type="checkbox" name="l_sync_ul" id="l_sync_ul" onclick="toggle_tip('ul_dept')">
```